# How to create and populate json object in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-cloud-functions

In Java, there is `JsonObject object= new JsonObject();` then one can add contents, how can I do this in node js?

Comment: Use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Create an object then `JSON.stringify(obj)` it.

Comment: Please show me an example @Andy

Comment: There are examples in the documenation that @dhilt added.

Comment: Not hard to research how to work with objects and json in javascript. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Great job, it's done

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Json derives from Javascript, it means "JavaScript Object Notation". Thus, in js it is just a plain object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = "bar";
```

Comment: No. JSON is the string representation of a JS object.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvotes - in Java a JsonObject behaves quite similarly to a plain Js object, with getters and setters to modify it. It implements a `Map<String,JsonValue>`. The values are distinct objects, and it is not just a string. This is what OP asked about.

Comment: Then that's the information you should have clarified in your answer. Because what you've written is misleading.

Comment: Well no, it accurately answers OP's question. Java's JsonObject simply immitates a plain Js object.

Comment: See, all of these additional comments are what you should have said in your answer. You didn't clarify that `JsonObject` can be considered a JS object. You wrote that JSON is just a plain object. Maybe you didn't intend that, but that's what that sentence reads, and why you were downvoted.